# Can't create HTML link in blade template with basic authentication parameters in URL

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I'd like to make this simple HTML link in blade template, Laravel 7.2.2:

```
<a href="http://user:pass@site.test">Test</a>
```

Laravel keeps removing "user:pass@" part. What I get is:

```
<a href="http://site.test">Test</a>
```

I've tried using `{!! !!}` syntax, tried `@php @endphp`, tried some tricks with replacing string fragments with `strtr` but nothing worked.

How do I output raw URL with login and password?

Comment: How have you tried?

Comment: So long as you are using this only for testing, no real worries here, but please reconsider this approach if you are using it in production. It looks like a pretty big security issue to me. The answer provided below should solve your issue though, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

The blade template engine is treating the `@site` as blade syntax and stripping it out.

Have you tried something like this:

```
<a href="{{ 'http://' . $user . ':' . $pass . '@' . 'site.test' }}">Test</a>
```

I don't claim this is the best solution! But by separating the `@` symbol from the text you may bypass the problem